# Sentry with Flask on AWS Lambda not capturing errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, sentry

I've deployed a flask application on AWS lambda. To perform error tracking I want to integrate Sentry into the application. Here is my setup for the application

```
def _handle_error(e):
    code = 500
    msg = 'Not Found'

    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        code = 404
    elif isinstance(e, ValueError):
        msg = str(e)

    logging.exception(e)

    if os.getenv('SENTRY_DSN'):
        event_id = sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
        logging.info(f'Error event was sent to sentry, event id: {event_id}')

    return jsonify({'error': msg}), code


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

    if os.getenv('SENTRY_DSN'):
        sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
            level=logging.DEBUG,     # Capture info and above as breadcrumbs
            event_level=logging.ERROR  # Send errors as events
        )

        sentry_sdk.init(dsn=os.getenv('SENTRY_DSN'),
                        integrations=[FlaskIntegration(), sentry_logging])

    app.register_blueprint(bp_routes)

    app.register_error_handler(Exception, _handle_error)
```

I use the custom error handler in flask to be able to return a generic error message without any sensitive information. When capturing the error I'm trying to manually create an event in Sentry

```
event_id = sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
```

Running the the code locally with `python application.py` everything works, the event is created in Sentry with the expected values.

When deploying the same code to lambda the event is no longer generated.

Also when I remove the custom flask error handler

```
# app.register_error_handler(Exception, _handle_error)
```

and deploy it to lambda the event IS generated!

Why is it the `capture_exception` not working on lambda?

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/aws_lambda/

Comment: Awesome, can you formulate it as an answer so I can close it

Comment: Awesome, can you formulate it as an answer so I can close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any web framework under AWS Lambda *additionally* requires the installation of the [AWS Lambda integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/aws_lambda/)

For services similar to AWS Lambda, the [generic serverless integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/serverless/) might become useful.